# I created symlinks between windows and ubuntu (ext4) partitions, and I think it's causing havoc, how do I hunt them down and remove them?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, symbolic-link

I want to remove all symlinks between my ntfs and ext4 partitions. Is there a simple way to find them, and then remove them? I am using windows 7 and 14.04.

I believe I used them to force my dropbox somewhere else, and also some system files possibly, causing me to not be able to use any MMC files.

Furthurmore, is there any evidence that this is bad practice? I am using ext4 partition manager to load my Ubuntu distro to be visible to windows.

Comment: If you are editing Dropbox folder without having dropbox running then yes, this is bad practice. And why would you force your dropbox elsewhere. The most important thing is to be sure you have the same rights on the folders you are linking to. But if you cant remember what you did how can we?

Comment: Isn't [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355260/46902) post answering your question?